# Proof of the limit for the sequence of function.

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, sequence-of-function

Here I need to prove / disprove that the limit for the sequence of functions is one. Here is what I have found:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n -e}=1 \\ \text{sequence }  \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \text{ upper limit is } e \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} sup = 0 \neq 1 $$

But why is the sup taken in order to disprove that the limit is not equal to 1?

Comment: the limit of a sequence exists iff the limsup and the liminf of the sequence coincide and in that case lim = limsup = liminf.

Comment: Actually, it's going to be $0^0$ form

Comment: However, limsup=0  implies the limit exists (and is equal to 0), since the liminf must be greater or equal to 0 but also less than limsup

Comment: @AlexR. I only have to prove/disprove that the limit is equal to 1.

Comment: Note that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<e$.  Hence, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-e<0$.  Inasmuch as $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is not defined for $x<0$ when $n$ is an even integer, the limit is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<e$.  Hence, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-e<0$.  Inasmuch as $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is not defined for $x<0$ when $n$ is an even integer, the limit is not well defined.

Instead, let's analyze the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$To proceed, we write

$$\begin{align}
e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=e\left(1-e^{n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-1}\right)\\\\
&=e\left(1-e^{-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}\right)\\\\
&=e\left(\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

whereupon taking the $n$th root and letting $n\to \infty$, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}=1$$

---

---

> **NOTE:  If we are permitted to broaden the definition of the $n$th root to be defined in terms of the complex logarithm, then for any fixed branch of the complex logarithm, the value of the original limit is also $1$.**

Comment: For some reason, I previously found that $\lim$ cannot be 1, because the sup of the function is 0. Can you change the sign under the square root and why?

Comment: The supremum is not $0$.  What leads you to believe that?

Comment: As $n \righarrow \infty$ $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \rightarrow e$ so the difference tends to 0. And what about the sign change?

Comment: The limit is of the indeterminate form $0^0$.  In this case, that limit is $1$ as I showed in the posted solution.  I'm happy to explain further if you tell me what part of the solution i posted is unclear.

Comment: @use1883  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.